# how to combine and sort two different tables together in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sorting

I have table A:

```
id username firstname event_date
1   Ben      lori     2014-01-27
2   Ben      lori     2014-01-04
3   Mary     john     2014-01-28
```

I have table B:

```
   id username event_date
   1   Ben     2014-01-23
   2   Nicole  2014-01-26
```

I want the result to be like this: Is there any solution that allow me to combine and sort it according to event_date  like one table,like this:

```
  2   Ben      lori     2014-01-04     
            1   Ben     2014-01-23
            2   Nicole  2014-01-26
  1   Ben      lori     2014-01-27
  3   Mary     john     2014-01-28
```

so that I can use something like while loop or mysql_fetch_assoc to display the content

Comment: You are lookong for `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need `union all`:

```
select id, username, firstname, event_date
from ((select id, username, firstname, event_date
       from tablea
      ) union all
      (select id, username, NULL as firstname, event_date
       from tablea
      )
     ) t
order by event_date;
```

Comment: will this query display sort the data all in separate row?

Comment: This query will return all the rows in the two tables, each on a separate row, sorted by the date.

Comment: and then I can access to the content in those row? for example, try to use while($array=mysql_fetch_assocs($query)){ echo $array['username'];  } the result would be 'ben ben nicole ben marry'

Comment: You would access it just as you would any result set from your application.  The `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: yes, I know, :),still struggling how should I change it into mysqli_query, because the whole website I have built using mysql_query, big trouble

Comment: can you explain 
"select id, username, NULL as firstname, event_date" more in details? and after this should be from `tableb`?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

`SELECT *
FROM tableA FULL OUTER JOIN tableB
ORDER BY event_date`

Comment: Maybe you're forgetting that MySQL doesn't have `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: And if it did, don't you need an `ON` clause to specify how the rows are joined? But he doesn't want to join them, he wants them to be separate rows in the result.

Comment: ops, I answered from smartphone while walking and didn't pay enough attention, sry. Bad answer